# Facebook API Integration

Tags: facebook

I want to avoid second login on my web-application. I want from my users who want to signup in my web application, then he/she login from facebook account and installed my facebook application, application ask for some permissions Full Name, Contact list, Primary Email, Chat, Messages. now my web-application linked on his facebook account. after then he/she logout from facebook the facebook session is destroyed and browser is closed
when he/she wants to login after 1,2 days. I don't want that user login again from facebook because he/she already logged before and our application is already linked on his account.Is this is possible. 
when he/she wants to login in my application so he/she can access chat/message and friendlist from facebook.

Comment: The JS SDK is able to recognizes users that have already connected to the app once before. For any other questions – please see docs first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use your app's access_token to make Facebook requests to publish graph requests but I don't think you can do everything you want. You need the user access token

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/